# DevIL library files and dependencies

Tags: c++, static-libraries, devil

Okay, here's the thing. I have all the IL files I need, namely

```
DevIL.dll
DevIL.lib

ILU.dll
ILU.lib

ILUT.dll
ILUT.lib

config.h
config.h.in
devil_cpp_wrapper.h
devil_internal_exports.h
il.h
ilu.h
ilu_region.h
ilut.h
ilut_config.h
```

My project directory looks like this, let's say my project's name is "Project1"

```
                 |-Debug---Project1.pdb
                 |
                 |            |---Debug---[loads of files]
                 |            |
                 |            |---Glut---[OpenGL files]
                 |            |
                 |            |---IL---[all the files mentioned above]
                 |-Project1---|
                 |            |---image.bmp
Project Folder---|            |
                 |            |---[header and .cpp files I made in the project]
                 |            |
                 |            |---[files produced by Visual Studio]
                 |          
                 |-ipch---[unrelated stuff]
                 |
                 |-Project1.sln
                 |
                 |-[other files VS created]
```

I've put all the DevIL files in the IL folder, as mentioned, and I am sure I am using the unicode compatible versions of them, as I am using Unicode Character Set for the project. In my "Additional Dependencies" I have

```
ilut.lib; ilu.lib; DevIL.lib;
```

So, the dependencies are there, I know that's not the problem.

After all that, I am still getting linker errors, mainly `LNK2019:unresolved external symbol__imp_` for all the IL functions.

What am I missing? It looks to me like maybe something to do with the project properties or the files themselves...maybe I missed a file?

EDIT: Here is the output messages

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Final Year Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 29/4/2011 12:46:04 pm.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Final Year Project.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\users\xxxx\desktop\final year project 0.2\final year project\main.cpp(152): warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
1>c:\users\xxxx\desktop\final year project 0.2\final year project\main.cpp(141): warning C4101: 'alpha' : unreferenced local variable
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilInit@0 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::Init(int,char * *)" (?Init@Main@@SAXHPAPAD@Z)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilDeleteImages@8 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilGetData@0 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilConvertImage@8 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilGetInteger@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilLoadImage@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilBindImage@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilGenImages@8 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Main::DisplayScene(void)" (?DisplayScene@Main@@SAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Final Year Project 0.2\Debug\Final Year Project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.93
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. Check the UNICODE thing again (did your really copy the right files? is the project configured for UNICODE? is _UNICODE defined too or just UNICODE?). Maybe delete and re-download every DevIL file, and make sure you copy the right version into your project folder.

Comment: I didn't define anything for Unicode, I just went, Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Character Set->Use Unicode Character Set.

Comment: @OddCore: MSVC normally defines UNICODE and _UNICODE if you switch a project to use Unicode strings (via a property sheet). Just do a check with #ifndef _UNICODE #error ... to make sure that's not the problem.

Comment: It cant be that complicated...what about files that need to go somewhere in Visual Studio 2010's directory? or system32? I'm sure that's the problem, although I have tried so many different approaches...and I have 3 different paths, Visual Studio, Visual Studio 09 and Visual Studio 10, not to mention Microsoft SDK and some other folders....

Comment: @OddCore: You don't need anything in the Visual Studio folders, also you don't need anything in the system32 folder. It would probably be helpful if you do a full rebuild and add the complete output of the build process (i.e. all messages including all errors). Guessing isn't that much fun, you know :)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post to show the output and errors....

Answer (score 4):

Since you added the build output, the answer is now easy: your linker errors have nothing to do with DevIL at all.

You need to link to [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (Simple DirectMedia Layer).

Since SDL has a C interface, and - IIRC - doesn't require that the DLL uses the same heap as the application, the [VC8 version of the "Development Libraries"](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-devel-1.2.14-VC8.zip) should do fine (even if you use VC10). Just add `SDL.lib` to the "Additional Dependencies" and you should be fine.

---

**EDIT**

OK.
You're either

1. not linking against the required .lib files (DevIL.lib etc.) or
2. linking against corrupted/wrong .lib files

At least there is no other explanation I can think of.
The names mentioned in your build log (`__imp__ilInit@0` etc.) are correct, and the current "DevIL SDK" ([DevIL 1.7.8 SDK for 32-bit Windows](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/openil/DevIL-SDK-x86-1.7.8.zip)) works fine with VC10 (I just verified it).

To assure you're linking against DevIL.lib etc. please put the following in your main.cpp file:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "DevIL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ILU.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ILUT.lib")
```

To make sure you're linking against the correct version of those files, re-download the whole SDK and try again with the new files.

---

**EDIT 2**

Since I got half the reward, I feel I should be more helpful :)

One last thing you can try: enable verbose linker output to check if the linker finds the correct version of `DevIL.lib`. (If it didn't find any `DevIL.lib`, you would get an error `LNK1104: cannot open file 'DevIL.lib'` - and since you're not getting that message, that cannot be the problem.)

To enable verbose linker output, add the `/VERBOSE` switch (under Configuration Settings -> Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options).

That will give you a ton of messages. Copy them into your favorite editor, and search for lines containing `DevIL.lib`. One of the lines should read `Searching X:\path\to\DevIL.lib:` - that's the path to the copy of `DevIL.lib` the linker is using. If that's not the path where you copied the files from the SDK you downloaded, you have found the problem.

And if there are no lines containing `DevIL.lib`, then the linker isn't even trying to locate it. However I've never seen `#pragma comment` fail, so if you indeed added those lines that almost surely cannot be the case.

BTW: please let me know if you managed to solve this. This is so strange that I really want to know what was going on :)

Comment: oh, crap. No, that wasn't the problem, what happened there was I was experimenting to see if SDL would work instead of DevIL, and forgot to switch it back to DevIL to post here....I'll edit the answer to show DevIL...

Comment: I re-downloaded DevIL from your link and I put all the files from the include and lib folders of the .rar in a folder in the project directory. I also added the three lines you mentioned, and built again but from what I can tell, the output is the same and no new errors have appeared. Do I need to put any files in any specific directory in the project directory? I read somewhere about having to put the DevIL.dll in the .exe folder (debug) but I tried it and nothing happened...

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the linker to link against the IL libs.

Project settings, Linker, Input

Make sure the directory the libs are in is in the Additional directorys field too.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed your config.h.in file should have .win extension because that it is in DevIL-SDK-x86-1.7.8.zip package. And there's no devil_cpp_wrapper.h file also.

Finally i solved this in this way:

1. Header files

   - config.h
   - config.h.win
   - devil_internal_exports.h
   - il.h
   - il_wrap.h
   - ilu.h
   - ilu_region.h
   - ilut.h
   - ilut_config.h

goes to VC include directory - all in one directory named IL (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\IL\ by default)

1. Liblary files

   - DevIL.lib
   - ILU.lib
   - ILUT.lib

goes to lib directory (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\ by default)

1. DLL files

   - DevIL.dll
   - ILU.dll
   - ILUT.dll

goes to project dorectory (...\Project Folder\Project1\ in your case)

Then i added liblary files to project by right click on project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies (wrote just name of liblaries like ILU.lib)

In my project I just include IL\il.h, IL\ilu.h and IL\ilut.h

I think you may got wrong files by the way...

Comment: Why do you think I have the wrong files? I got them from the link pgroke posted above, they should be the right ones...

Comment: also, I have a file called config.h.win, if I did not mention, in the same directory as the others.

Comment: Files you listed in first post are not exacly that i found in DevIL-SDK-x86-1.7.8.zip, that's all. I didn't  mention that I copied.lib and .dll files form unicode directory(...lib\unicode\). Did you try my method?

Comment: it runs when you include IL\il.h, IL\ilu.h and IL\ilut.h
but fails when you call: ilInit();    iluInit();   ilutInit();

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you never got this worked out, or anyone else has the same problem (like I did):
I had downloaded the 64-bit version of DevIL for my 64-bit Windows computer, but Microsoft Visual Studio (I was using Express) was the 32-bit version.
I downloaded the 32-bit version of DevIL and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Seems like the pre-built binaries are swapped: I could link to the ones designated as non-unicode but they would utterly fail trying to use my non-unicode strings and return unicode strings. Try to build your own binaries from the source or use a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

you should compare the function signatures that you see in your errors with the signatures you get with depends.exe (depedency walker). If they differ there may be a compiler-issue.
You may then try to compile with :

```
extern "C" {
 // put your devils-include directives here ...
}
```

Nothing garantied of course , just a suggestion.

You may also check the '**Additional Library Directories**' property on your '**Linker\General**' page to see if (when used) it points to the right directory for your build (if you also added a path to the standard VC lib-directories their may be a conflict ,use either one but not both).

Another suggestion is to create a new project and do it all over again ,you may have made an ever so little mistake.

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In my case it was problem with code in all devil`s .h files

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #if (defined(IL_USE_PRAGMA_LIBS)) && (!defined(_IL_BUILD_LIBRARY))
        #if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
            #pragma comment(lib, "%LIBNAME%.lib")
        #endif
    #endif
#endif
```

after second #if code was deactivated.
i added `#pragma comment(lib, "DevIL.lib")` (and 2 more) into my main.h and linker errors dissapeared.

sorry for my bad english =[

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question is still active, but since it has no chosen answer, I'll post this. I had what seems like the exact same problem with DevIL version 1.7.8. To fix it, I rolled back the version to 1.7.7 and used #undef _UNICODE before including the headers and #define _UNICODE afterwards. The project compiled without linker errors and worked without a hitch. On 1.7.8, the libraries seem to all be unicode, or at least they don't seem to support ascii very well. However, this may just be some weird compatibility issue with my computer as it does not seem to be a common problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have to declare some preprocessor variable to actually tell the compiler that you are importing symbol; I mean something related to `__declspec( dllimport )`

Comment: That's already taken care of, otherwise the missing import wouldn't end with "imp_".

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly as what [Sarah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304113/2498132) said about the 32-bit or 64-bit Visual Studio versions. I'm on a 64-bit computer running a 32-bit Visual Studio 2012. I obtained this error when I used the x64 DevIL files. Getting the x86 version helped. Here's the basic steps I took to ensure it does run:

**Right-click** your project and go to **Properties**.

Under **C/C++ > General**, add DevIL's '**include**' folder under **Additional Include Directories**.

Then under **Linker > General**, add DevIL's '**lib**' folder (it should contain: DevIL.lib, ILU.lib and ILUT.lib)  to **Additional Library Directories**. For x64 it may not contain a lib folder, it may be just the DevIL directory itself (for version 1.7.8 it was that case).

Also in **Linker > Input**, add those .lib file names into **Additional Dependencies**.

Now that should be all you need to do in the project properties. In the main.cpp you should include the appropriate header files and it should work when you initialize.

Example:

```
#include "IL/il.h"
#include "IL/ilu.h"
#include "IL/ilut.h"

int main(){
   ilInit();
   iluInit();
   ilutRenderer(ILUT_OPENGL); //these are just to initialize
}
```