# Including error DevIL/ResIL image library in project

Tags: c++, dll, include, devil, imagelibrary

I try to compile a sample code using the Devil image library.
I already found this link:
[DevIL library files and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743235/devil-library-files-and-dependencies)  but this doesn't help me further

I already included the IL directory with its contents and the lib files to the project
I get no IntelliSense warnings, so the funcions are recognized(using VS 2010)?!
But whenever I compile I get the error in a messagebox that DevIL.dll couldn't be find.

The sample code looks like this:
http://www.fpaste.org/98724/90701801/

Does anybody have a solution how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: You have to add the dlls in the debug directory